# Howto convert Pandas Datetime Column from EST WITHOUT Day Light Savings adjustments into CET WITH Day Light Savings adjustments

Tags: pandas, datetime, timezone, dst

I have a dataset with a datetime column where the timezone is Eastern Standard Time (EST) WITHOUT Day Light Savings adjustments. How can I convert the column into Central European Time (CET) WITH Day Light Savings adjustments using pandas?

I assume I have to make the column time zone aware by using pandas.DataFrame.tz_localize and then convert the tz-aware Datetime column from one time zone to another with pandas.DataFrame.tz_convert. How do I set the correct daylight savings adjustment option?
Can somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you already have the approach for converting from one time zone to another, and just need to know how to specify the time zones to match your use case.

- For the input time zone, if all data is truly from EST (UTC-5) without daylight saving time, even when EDT (UTC-4) might be in effect in US Eastern Time, then use the identifier `Etc/GMT+5`.  (Note the inverted sign `+` is correct, due to reasons not worth getting into here.)  This is a fixed-offset zone, so you're not really applying "Eastern Time", but rather just "UTC-5".
- For the output time zone, decide *where* in Central Europe you want to convert to.  This matters because not every location that uses CET/CEST has always been aligned in the same way.  For example, you can choose `Europe/Paris`, `Europe/Berlin`, or `Europe/Budapest`, as well as many others.

You can find a list of these time zone identifiers [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Comment: Hello Matt Johnson-Pint,
thank you very much for your help. Sorry, that I am answering so late.
That means I just have to do the following steps:
1) convert from EST to UTC (without daylight savings)
2) convert from UTC to CET (with daylight savings)
3) remove time zone information => naive datetime
**(df['datetime']+pd.Timedelta(hours=5)).dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin').dt.tz_localize(None)**

Comment: The 3rd step 'remove time zone information' could cause problems on dates where the time gets adjusted from summer to winter time because I would get datetime duplicates.
So this should be the preferable solution in my case:
**(df['datetime']+pd.Timedelta(hours=5)).dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin')**

Comment: Why `+` ? Why not something like `df['datetime'].dt.tz_localize('Etc/GMT+5').tz_convert('Europe/Berlin')`?  You don't have to go through UTC in the middle if the source is tz aware.

Comment: Hi Matt, I was not 100% sure about the handling of the daylight savings. But df['datetime'].dt.tz_localize('Etc/GMT+5').dt.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin') delivers exactly the same result. Thank you for your help.